# Can't open Preferences in Safari 11

Tags: safari, high-sierra

I'm not sure what's going on, but suddenly I can't open Preferences in Safari. Nothing happens at all.

This might have to do with the fact that I installed Safari 12, then realized I couldn't downgrade, so I manually removed Safari 12 (after disabling SIP) via `sudo rm -rf /Applications/Safari.app`, then restored Safari 11 via Time Machine.

It works in every other way, except Preferences.

Comment: Any errors in Console.app?

Answer (score 1):

I would be willing to bet that Safari 11 can't read the Safari 12 preferences file(s). No doubt part of the upgrade process is to make changes to these files to reflect the differences between the two versions.

Of course Apple is not going to tell you about this because going *back to an earlier version* who would do that? (GASP!)

You are probably have to play the preferences dance, eg start removing preferences files associated with Safari until it starts working again on your Mac.

Open a Finder window, hold down Option and go to the "Go" Menu and select Library. In that folder find Preferences and then look for things that start with "Com.Apple.Safari" on my Mac it looks like this.

[image: Safari Preferences Files]

It could be a little different on your Mac any one (or all) of these files could be unreadable by your version of Safari. So quit the app, move one of these to the desktop and relaunch Safari, until it works.

More bad news: there is **also** a "Safari" folder in Library, any one or more of these files could also be a problem. SO you may have to repeat that routine again with the files in there.

Comment: Sadly, even after moving all the aforementioned files, preferences in Safari still won't open.

Comment: then it is likely that installing the newer version of Safari changed something in WebKit (or the like...) deep in the system. So reverting is going to mean backing up your files and wiping and reinstalling the OS

Comment: Ugh. What a royal pain.